# @Angular/Material Tooltip global "mdTooltipShowDelay"

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm using the MdTooltipModule in my Angular4 Project to show tooltips to the user. I include the tooltip like so:

```
   <a *ngFor="let option of optionsToggle"
       mdTooltip="{{option.name | translate}}"
       mdTooltipShowDelay="1000"
       mdTooltipPosition="left">
      <i class="material-icons">{{option.icon}}</i>
    </a>
```

Although this works fine, I would like to globally set the showDelay just once for my whole project, and don't repeat this all the time. Is there any easy way to achieve this?
I guess using the binding [mdTooltipShowDelay]="value" could help, but this won't access static variables and I don't want to initalize it in every component.

Comment: I think according to https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/tooltip/tooltip.ts is not possible to inject somehow default values to the component. This is in fact a really poor design in my opinion, as allowing an easy global configuration for such parameters should be possible without to much effort. You could create an issue in the angular repo related to this

Comment: The template can only access fields and methods of the component class. Everything else is inaccessible. This includes things which are visible to the component class.

Comment: There is an open issue for this https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3286. Shouldn't be too hard to implement, but it looks low priority

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From **Angular Material v5.1.0**, is implemented `MAT_TOOLTIP_DEFAULT_OPTIONS` injection token, that can be used to override the default options for `matTooltip`.

```
const MAT_TOOLTIP_DEFAULT_OPTIONS: InjectionToken<MatTooltipDefaultOptions>;
```

In **Angular Material v8**, `MatTooltipDefaultOptions` has the following structure, as described [here](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/api#MatTooltipDefaultOptions):

```
export interface MatTooltipDefaultOptions {
  showDelay: number;
  hideDelay: number;
  touchendHideDelay: number;
  position?: TooltipPosition;
}
```

The defaults for these values are, as found [here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/tooltip/tooltip.ts#L117):

```
{
  showDelay: 0,
  hideDelay: 0,
  touchendHideDelay: 1500,
}
```

---

A simple implementation would be:

```
...
import {MAT_TOOLTIP_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, MatTooltipDefaultOptions} from '@angular/material';

export const myCustomTooltipDefaults: MatTooltipDefaultOptions = {
  showDelay: 1000,
  hideDelay: 500,
  touchendHideDelay: 1000,
};

@NgModule({
    imports: [...],
    providers: [
        {provide: MAT_TOOLTIP_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: myCustomTooltipDefaults}
    ],
})
```

Demo on [Stacklitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vbi9gf).

---

Alternatively, we can inject the default options on component level. Following this approach, we can have multiple components with different defaults.
We can have a component with:

```
export const fooCustomTooltipDefaults: MatTooltipDefaultOptions = {
  showDelay: 1000,
  hideDelay: 500,
  touchendHideDelay: 1000,
};
@Component({
     selector: 'foo',
     templateUrl: './foo.component.html',
     providers: [
       {provide: MAT_TOOLTIP_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: fooCustomTooltipDefaults}
     ],
})
```

And another component:

```
export const barCustomTooltipDefaults: MatTooltipDefaultOptions = {
  showDelay: 2000,
  hideDelay: 0,
  touchendHideDelay: 1000,
};

@Component({
     selector: 'bar',
     templateUrl: './bar.component.html',
     providers: [
       {provide: MAT_TOOLTIP_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: barCustomTooltipDefaults}
     ],
})
```

Demo on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eftknf).

---

Angular Material documentation: 
https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/api#MAT_TOOLTIP_DEFAULT_OPTIONS

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works like a charm and also seems to be supported across a wide range of other material element parameters!

Comment: Recommend calling MAT_TOOLTIP_DEFAULT_OPTIONS_FACTORY() to get the default options and only overriding the ones you need to.

Answer (score 0):

## When configuration ⚙️ comes from "outside"

When configuration comes from a back-end api that is requested "somewhere" in the initalisation process of the application the `MatTooltipDefaultOptions` can be updated as following:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_TOOLTIP_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, MatTooltipDefaultOptions } from '@angular/material/tooltip';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class Service {
    public constructor(@Inject(MAT_TOOLTIP_DEFAULT_OPTIONS) matTooltipDefaultOptions: MatTooltipDefaultOptions, httpClient: HttpClient) {
        httpClient.get('https://some.base.url/configuration').subscribe((response: any) => {
            matTooltipDefaultOptions.showDelay = response.tooltipShowDelay;
        });
    }
}
```